# Python Pandas: How to replace to_csv string quoting from double quotes to single quotes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe where one of the column(col2) has many commas hence when pandas output to a CSV file, it by defaults encloses that field value in double quotes.
How do i specify that i want single quotes for columns with commas?

df:

```
col1  col2     col3
1    x;y,b;c  blabla

df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

current CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3
 1,"x;y,b;c",blabla
```

I want single quotes instead:

```
col1,col2,col3
 1,'x;y,b;c',blabla
```

Comment: most csv imports expect double quotes, sure this is a good idea?

Comment: That is because i need to use a java file next to read in the CSV file. somehow that requires the quotes to be in single quotes.

Comment: `df.to_csv(..., quotechar="'")`

Comment: @MaxU - I test it, you are right, add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `quotechar="'"` parameter:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   col1     col2    col3
0     1  x;y,b;c  blabla

In [42]: print(df.to_csv(index=False, quotechar="'"))
col1,col2,col3
1,'x;y,b;c',blabla
```